# Boost.Python: Take possession of argument

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

If I have a function that takes possession of one of the arguments, are there any call policies that I should use when I expose that function with Boost.Python?

```
void func(MyClass* obj)
{
    // Code that takes possession of `obj`
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question but, are you worried that some other function modifies the passed object? If so (and if you can modify the function), maybe `boost::weak_ptr` is what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "take possession" ?

Comment: Take possession as in, it might want to delete it. Or it might store it somewhere and then have it be deleted at some later point.

Comment: can you change the function to take an auto_ptr<MyClass>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `boost::weak_ptr`.

```
using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::weak_ptr;

func (weak_ptr<MyClass> wp)
{
  shared_ptr<MyClass> sp = wp.lock ();
  if (sp)
    // sp stays alive until it goes out of scope or is reset
}
```

Basically, this is the example offered in the documentation of `boost::weak_ptr`.
Here's the [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm).

Comment: If the function takes `shared_ptr`, it will work just the same: you ensure object will not get deleted before the function returns. And you save the locking code. What should be the difference?

Comment: If I got it correctly, if you don't use `weak_ptr`+locking, you cannot be sure that no one messes around with the object pointed by your `shared_ptr`. The `shared_ptr` created using `lock ()`, points to the object that ''was'' pointed by the `weak_ptr` at the time of locking and ensure that the object lives until that `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: See [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm). `weak_ptr` is useful to hold pointer to a shared object to be used (perhaps) later, without preventing its deletion. Here you get `weak_ptr` and immediately convert it to `shared_ptr` with `lock()`, what's the purpose?